# Changing source file type to Objective-C++ causes linker error when using GameKit

Tags: c++, objective-c, gamekit

So I am using Xcode 6.1 on my Objective-C app.
My app uses the GameKit framework.

I tried to call external C++ methods from my GameViewController (which is Objective-C source.)

To make GameViewController.mm compile, I had to set the type to 'Objective-C++ Source' manually.

However, even though the source now compiles, it will fail to link with:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GameViewController in GameViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLKViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GameViewController in GameViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can only get rid of the linker error by setting the type back to 'Objective-C Source' and removing the calls to the external C++ functions.

Why does the linker fail if my source is compiled as 'Objective-C++ Source' instead of 'Objective-C Source' type?

Note that I properly link against GameKit in the Build-phases.

Comment: isn't `.mm` files automatically compiled as ObjC++ code? why you need to set it manually? anyway you may need add reference to GLKit

Comment: Keep in mind that *any* class that imports/includes a C++ header either directly or indirectly (importing another header that imports a C++ header) will need the .mm extension. If you put the C++ headers in the prefix, then all source files need to be .mm.

Comment: Wow, weird one this - I had to manually add the GLKit framework in Xcode 8.0 after changing from .m to .mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.
It turns out to be a weird one, but:

I was linking to GameKit, and not GLKit.
The fix: link to GLKit as well.

Now, the strange part is that not linking GLKit causes no problems if the view controller is built as Objective-C source. It does cause problems if built as Objective-C++ source.

Strange, but true.

Comment: when build as ObjC code, clang translate `#import` to `@import` which does the linking. I guess this feature is not enabled for ObjC++

Comment: I had a similar issue, so I found this very useful. I had to specify to link against the MediaPlayer framework (which the program would be linked against anyway in Objective-C mode I guess) when I changed the source type to Objective-C++. Thanks!