# Linker errors after changing source file type to Objective-C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0

I have an OpenGL ES 2.0 application, and would like to use C++ code in a view controller implementation. However, after changing the file extension to mm (or even just adjust the source type without changing the filename), the following errors are encountered during linking:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

> "_GLKMatrix4Identity", referenced from:
>         GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(float, float, float) in GameViewController.o
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLKViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GameViewController in GameViewController.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_GameViewController in GameViewController.o
>     "_GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose", referenced from:
>         -[GameViewController update] in GameViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manually added the GLKit framework in build phases settings.
(Interesting question though - why didn't the app require it when no C++ source was involved -- how could it possibly compile and run?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139655/changing-source-file-type-to-objective-c-causes-linker-error-when-using-gameki#comment42778815_27140067